# Pythonic Way to reverse nested dictionaries

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a nested dictionary of people and item ratings, with people as the key. people may or may not share items.
Example:

```
{
 'Bob' : {'item1':3, 'item2':8, 'item3':6},
 'Jim' : {'item1':6, 'item4':7},
 'Amy' : {'item1':6,'item2':5,'item3':9,'item4':2}
}
```

I'm looking for the simplest way to flip these relations, and have a new nested dictionary with items as the key.
Example:

```
{'item1' : {'Bob':3, 'Jim':6, 'Amy':6},
 'item2' : {'Bob':8, 'Amy':5},
 'item3' : {'Bob':6, 'Amy':9},
 'item4' : {'Jim':7, 'Amy':2}
}
```

What is the best way to do this? Is it possible with a comprehension?

Comment: Comprehensions are not necessarily always a good idea when in situations like these where **readability counts**.

Comment: @jathanism, very true. I'm still learning Python, and wasn't sure if there a cleaner, more 'pythonic' implementation of what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) makes this pretty simple:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pprint

data = {
 'Bob' : {'item1':3, 'item2':8, 'item3':6},
 'Jim' : {'item1':6, 'item4':7},
 'Amy' : {'item1':6,'item2':5,'item3':9,'item4':2}
}

flipped = defaultdict(dict)
for key, val in data.items():
    for subkey, subval in val.items():
        flipped[subkey][key] = subval

pprint.pprint(dict(flipped))
```

Output:

```
{'item1': {'Amy': 6, 'Bob': 3, 'Jim': 6},
 'item2': {'Amy': 5, 'Bob': 8},
 'item3': {'Amy': 9, 'Bob': 6},
 'item4': {'Amy': 2, 'Jim': 7}}
```

Comment: The credit for the ease of this doesn't really go to defaultdict, IMHO, since it's really just as easy without it, just adding the line "flipped.setdefault(subkey, {})"

Answer (score 4):

I totally agree that Ryan Ginstrom's answer is the preferred way of doing this (for all practical purposes).

But since the question also explicitely asks:

***Is it possible with a comprehension?***

I thought I'd chime in with a quick example as for how to do this with a list comprehension (it could be a good example for showing how nested list comphrehensions can quickly decrease readability).

```
import itertools

d = {
 'Bob' : {'item1':3, 'item2':8, 'item3':6},
 'Jim' : {'item1':6, 'item4':7},
 'Amy' : {'item1':6,'item2':5,'item3':9,'item4':2}
}

print dict([(x, dict([(k, d[k][x]) for k,v in d.items() if x in d[k]])) 
            for x in set(itertools.chain(*[z for z in d.values()]))])
```

Comment: nice. it does look like a pretty hairy comprehension, but +1 for providing it.

Comment: This is better done with generator expressions, the `iter*` methods of dictionaries, and `chain.from_iterable` (new in 2.6). This way, only the set needs to be held in memory rather than a bunch of lists constructed temporarily. `dict((x, dict((k, d[k][x]) for k,v in d.iteritems() if x in d[k])) for x in set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(d.itervalues())))`

Answer (score 1):

This is easy enough to do (as others have shown), but depending on your needs you should also consider that for data with several pieces of information where you want to extract by any criterion, a database might be the best tool. The built-in `sqlite3` module provides a low-overhead database that may, depending on what you are doing, serve you better than a nested dict.

Comment: this is true, and worth considering. But the data I get could come from a variety of sources (json, xml, db, etc) so I was looking at ways to approach things using language constructs instead of relying on the source.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas can provide another option. Assume `data` is the input dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd
output = {i:s.dropna().to_dict() for i, s in pd.DataFrame(data).T.iteritems()}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just access reverse nested dictionaries,
Save memory if the dictionary is too large to reverse.

```
class mdict2(dict):
    def __init__(self, parent, key1):
        self.parent = parent
        self.key1 = key1

    def __getitem__(self, key2):
        return self.parent.mirror[key2][self.key1]


class mdict(dict):
    def __init__(self, mirror):
        self.mirror = mirror

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return mdict2(self, key)

d0 = {
 'Bob' : {'item1':3, 'item2':8, 'item3':6},
 'Jim' : {'item1':6, 'item4':7},
 'Amy' : {'item1':6,'item2':5,'item3':9,'item4':2}
}
d1 = mdict(d0)

d0['Amy']['item1'] == d1['item1']['Amy']
# True
```