# how to create a pivot nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, pivot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pythonic Way to reverse nested dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273691/pythonic-way-to-reverse-nested-dictionaries)

I am having hard time trying to find a solution for this nested dictionary problem.
I found some itertools functions that could be used, but it is not clear to me as how to use it. any help on this front would be great

```
input = { "a" : { "x": 1, "y": 2 },
          "b" : { "x": 3, "z": 4 } }


output = {'y': {'a': 2},
          'x': {'a': 1, 'b': 3},
          'z': {'b': 4} }
```

Comment: It's not clear. Do you just "reverse" the keys?

Comment: I've seen this question before, but I can't find it :(

Comment: Ah ha! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273691/pythonic-way-to-reverse-nested-dictionaries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simplistic way using `dict.setdefault`:

```
i = { "a" : { "x": 1, "y": 2 },
      "b" : { "x": 3, "z": 4 } }

d = {}
for key, value in i.iteritems():    
    for ikey, ivalue in value.iteritems():
        d.setdefault(ikey,{})[key] = ivalue
print d
```

out:

```
{'x': {'a': 1, 'b': 3}, 'y': {'a': 2}, 'z': {'b': 4}}
```