# Python reversing nested dictionaries

Tags: python, nested, reverse, dictionary

I want to take a nested dictionary and reverse the values 
for example

```
input = { "a" : { "x": 2, "y": 3 },
          "b" : { "x": 5, "z": 7 } }
output = {'y': {'a': 3},
          'x': {'a': 2, 'b': 5},
          'z': {'b': 7} }
```

what I have:

```
def reverse_nest_dicts(nested_dict):
    reverse_nest_dict = {}
    for k, v in nested_dict:
        for k2, v2 in nested_dict.values():
            reverse_nest_dict[k2][k] = v2
    return reverse_nest_dict
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for k2, v2 in nested_dict.values():
```

should be

```
for k2, v2 in v.items():
```

(Also note that if you're using Python 2.x, it may be more efficient to use `.iteritems()` instead of `.items()`.)

---

You also need to make sure the sub-dictionaries are initialized - you can do this by either using `defaultdict`...

```
from collections import defaultdict
reverse_nest_dict = defaultdict(dict)
```

...or by using `setdefault`:

```
reverse_nest_dict.setdefault(k2, {})[k] = v2
```

Comment: also, reverse_nest_dict either needs to be a collections.defaultdict(dict) or reverse_nest_dict[k2] has to be manually initialized to an empty dict

Comment: I like "reverse_nest_dict.setdefault(k2, {})[k] = v2"... nicer than the way I've been doing it so far (try...except).

Comment: Yes, though `defaultdict` is potentially more efficient (especially if the initialization value were a more complex object).

Answer (score 1):

Your function has three different errors. The following is what you are after:

```
def reverse_nest_dicts(nested_dict):
    reverse_nest_dict = {}
    for k, v in nested_dict.iteritems():
        for k2, v2 in v.iteritems():
            try:
                reverse_nest_dict[k2][k] = v2
            except KeyError:
                reverse_nest_dict[k2] = { k : v2 }
    return reverse_nest_dict
```

The errors are:

- 1st for loop: using the dictionary as loop sequence will result in keys only, you want (key,value) so need to use items() or iteritems()
- 2nd for loop: the loop sequence should be the nested dictionary, not the outer dictionary
- you need to initialise the reverse_nest_dict values to inner dictionaries before you try to access them.

Answer (score 1):

The [dictionary *items()* and *setdefault()* methods](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict) make short work of this kind of problem:

```
>>> input = { "a" : { "x": 2, "y": 3 },
              "b" : { "x": 5, "z": 7 } }
>>> result = {}
>>> for k1, subdict in input.items():
        for k2, v in subdict.items():
            result.setdefault(k2, {})[k1] = v

>>> result
{'y': {'a': 3}, 'x': {'a': 2, 'b': 5}, 'z': {'b': 7}}
```

In Python 2, you can get a minor speed boost by using *iteritems()* instead of *items()*.

Likewise, the use of *collections.defaultdict(dict)* can be a little faster than using *setdefault*.  Of course, that will return a defaultdict instead of a dict as specified in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If the dictionary is too large, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/47151034/676214

> If you want just access reverse nested dictionaries,
>   Save memory if the dictionary is too large to reverse.

```
class mdict2(dict):
    def __init__(self, parent, key1):
        self.parent = parent
        self.key1 = key1

    def __getitem__(self, key2):
        return self.parent.mirror[key2][self.key1]


class mdict(dict):
    def __init__(self, mirror):
        self.mirror = mirror

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return mdict2(self, key)

d0 = {
 'Bob' : {'item1':3, 'item2':8, 'item3':6},
 'Jim' : {'item1':6, 'item4':7},
 'Amy' : {'item1':6,'item2':5,'item3':9,'item4':2}
}
d1 = mdict(d0)

d0['Amy']['item1'] == d1['item1']['Amy']
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NestedDict`. First install [ndicts](https://github.com/edd313/ndicts)

```
pip install ndicts
```

Then

```
from ndicts.ndicts import NestedDict

input_dict = {"a": { "x": 2, "y": 3 }, "b": { "x": 5, "z": 7 }}
nd = NestedDict(input_dict)
reversed_nd = NestedDict()

for key, value in nd.items():
    reversed_key = tuple(reversed(key))
    reversed_nd[reversed_key] = value
```

Finally

```
>>> reversed_nd.to_dict()
{'x': {'a': 2, 'b': 5}, 'y': {'a': 3}, 'z': {'b': 7}}
```