# Turn a dictionary of lists in to a list of dictionaries in Python 2.7

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have this

```
original = {
   "state_id": "1,2",
   "name": "A,B"
}
```

I can easily turn in to this

```
original_splitted = {k: v.split(',') for k, v in original.iteritems()}
{
   "state_id": ['1', '2'],
   "name": ['A' ,'B']
}
```

But what I want is this:

```
[
    {"state_id": '1', "name": "A"}, 
    {"state_id": '2', "name": "B"} 
]
```

I am looking for a cool "one-liner" comprehension magic to achieve this (avoiding the use of large nested loops)

Comment: It's almost like you want to [pivot your dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273691/pythonic-way-to-reverse-nested-dictionaries). I'm thinking an cool, one-liner is going to be incomprehensible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a 2-liner using `zip(*)` and a list comprehension:

```
>>> vals = zip(*(x.split(',') for x in original.itervalues()))
>>> [dict(zip(original, v)) for v in vals]
[{'state_id': '1', 'name': 'A'}, {'state_id': '2', 'name': 'B'}]
```

Comment: `izip` can't prevent the splat from turning `(x.split(',') for x in original.itervalues())` into a tuple of arguments, so I doubt it'll do much good.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that the iteration order of a dict is guaranteed not to change while the dict doesn't change, so you can safely zip the dict with `v` without worrying about keys getting mapped to the wrong values.

Comment: @user2357112 Ah! yes. Removed that part.

Comment: So it can be done in one line
    ```[dict(zip(original, v)) for v in zip(*(x.split(',') for x in original.itervalues()))]```